# Plugin update and error notifications

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created a custom plugin for Wordpress which has some custom tables etc. After the processing of data I either show a confirmation or an error message (this is in the wp-admin side). I've been using the WordPress classes to use the default theming, like so:

```
<?php if ( ! empty($success)): ?>
<div class="updated">
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($success as $message): ?>
    <li><?php echo $message; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ( ! empty($errors)): ?>
<div class="error">
    <ul>
    <?php foreach ($errors as $error): ?>
    <li><?php echo $error; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<!-- HTML STARTS HERE -->
<div class="wrap">
```

The weird thing is that when the errors or success messages are output, they appear in a different part of the HTML. I can't understand why. In some cases it's a good few nodes into the DOM tree, e.g.

```
<!-- In the code it's here (as shown above)... -->

<div class="wrap">
    <section>
        <header>
            <div>
                <!-- BUT IT SHOWS UP HERE, WHAT!? -->
            </div>
        </header>
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's done on purpose by the following lines in [`wp-admin/js/common.js`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9/src/wp-admin/js/common.js#L343):

```
// Move .updated and .error alert boxes. Don't move boxes designed to be inline.
$('div.wrap h2:first').nextAll('div.updated, div.error').addClass('below-h2');
$('div.updated, div.error').not('.below-h2, .inline').insertAfter( $('div.wrap h2:first') );
```

I don't know the rationale for this but I suspect it's for styling purposes. The only tickets I found were [#27688](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/27688) and  [#14860](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14860) but they explain little.

Comment: Good find dude - does seem like a bizarre (lazy) thing to do.